# How to store a HashMap in a database whose values are Arrays?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, hashmap

I'm trying to store a `HashMap` that will contain `Arrays` as values.

When I query the database, I would like to retrieve the `hashmap` as a `java` object so that I can perform operations on it as if it were simply a `hashmap` within the `java` program.

Is this possible? Would something like `Hibernate` work here?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hibernate, yes, but... when modelling a database, you don't need to think of the relations as HashMaps.

Instead, think of each relation.
HashMap is key => value. In your case, the 'value' is an array list, which in a database is represented by a 1:N relationship.

So all you want is a class called 'Key' with an array of values inside it.
You can use hibernate to create 1:N mappings in a very easy way, yes. So when you get the element with a certain key, you will also get your entire array list automatically.

1:N / 1->n in hibernate is called one to many. Check this link :
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/

Comment: just adding some information that might be obvious... the Key class will have an ID and it will have its own table in the DB.

The Value class will have an ID of its own, of course, but also a pointer to the Key (like a 'fk_key_id' foreign key) so that hibernate will be able to tell "how to get all Value objects for a determined key.